# How to create one node from multiple nodes having same name using xsl?

Tags: xml, xslt

My XML structure is like

```
<Client>
  <Document>
    <service class="ABC">
      <author name="x"/>
      <Details>
        ...
      </Details>
    </service>
   </Document>
   <Document>
     <service class="ABC">
       <author name="x"/>
       <Details>
         ...
       </Details>
     </service>
   </Document>
   <Document>
     <service class="ABC">
       <author name="x"/>
       <Details>
         ...
       </Details>
     </service>
   </Document>'
</Client>
```

I want it like

```
<Client>
  <Document>
    <service class="ABC">
      <author name="x"/>
       <Details>
         ...
       </Details>
    </service>
   </Document>
   <Document>
     <service class="ABC">
       <author name="x"/>
       <Details>
         ...
       </Details>
     </service>
   </Document>
   <Document>
     <service class="ABC">
       <author name="x"/>
       <Details>
         ...
       </Details>
     </service>
   </Document>'
   <component>
     <service class="ABC">
       <author name="x"/>
     </service>
   </component>'
</Client>
```

My xsl file contains

```
<xsl:template match="//v3:Client">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
      <component>
        <service class="">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="//v3:Client/v3:Document/v3:service/v3:author"/>
        </service>
      </component>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="//v3:Client/v3:component/v3:service">
    <xsl:element name="service" namespace="urn:hl7-org:v3">
      <xsl:attribute name="class">
        <xsl:value-of select="//v3:Client/v3:Document/v3:service/@class"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
```

But its not giving desired output. Its giving output like

```
Client
  Document
    service class="ABC"
      author name="x"
      details
        ...
      details
     service
    Document
   Document
    service class="ABC"
      author name="x"
      details
        ...
      details
    service
  Document
  Document
    service class="ABC"
      author name="x"
      details
        ...
      details
    service
  Document
  component
    service class=""
      author name="x"
    service
    service class=""
      author name="x"
    service
    service class=""
      author name="x"
    service
  component
Client
```

I'm new to xsl. Can anybody please help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to output the distinct **service** elements in your **component** element, then in XSTL1.0 you need to use a technique called **Muenchian Grouping**. I am assuming the **class** attribute uniquely identifies a service, so you would start by defining a key to look up the services like so

```
<xsl:key name="service" match="service" use="@class" />
```

Then, when creating your **component** element, to get the distinct **service** elements you have look at all such elements, but only select the ones that occur first in the key for their given **class** attribute.

```
<xsl:apply-templates 
     select="Document/service[generate-id() = generate-id(key('service', @class)[1])]" 
     mode="component" />
```

Within the template that matches the **service** element, you can just output the details as requires. In your sample it looks like you only want the **author** element here, as opposed to the **details** too.

```
<xsl:template match="service" mode="component">
   <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="author|@*"/>
   </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

The use of **mode** is because you only want this template matching when you are outputing the compenent element.

Here is the full XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:key name="service" match="service" use="@class" />

<xsl:template match="Client">
   <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     <component>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Document/service[generate-id() = generate-id(key('service', @class)[1])]" mode="component" />
     </component>
   </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="service" mode="component">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="author|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your sample XML, the following is output

```
<Client>
   <Document>
      <service class="ABC">
         <author name="x"/>
         <Details> ... </Details>
      </service>
   </Document>
   <Document>
      <service class="ABC">
         <author name="x"/>
         <Details> ... </Details>
      </service>
   </Document>
   <Document>
      <service class="ABC">
         <author name="x"/>
         <Details> ... </Details>
      </service>
   </Document>
   <component>
      <service class="ABC">
         <author name="x"/>
      </service>
   </component>
</Client>
```

Comment: Thank you for reply.
Here problem is that all service nodes have same class value.

Comment: Could you perhaps edit your question to show an example where the service nodes have different class values? Thanks!

Comment: Did just a minor change and it worked.
Thanks a lot. All answers are really helpful but this solution fitted best.
Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

Use `group-by` feature:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="/Client">

    <xsl:copy-of select="Document" />

    <!-- Group nodes by attribute value, produce one <component>
         per each group -->
    <xsl:for-each-group select="Document" group-by="service/@class">
      <component>
        <xsl:copy-of select="./service" />
      </component>
    </xsl:for-each-group>

  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Stylesheet above produces one `<component>` per each `Document class=""` attribute value.

Comment: Thank you so much for quick reply.
I want only one <component> node and want to merge all <document> nodes to one <component> node. I also want to set value of attribute class from <service> node.

Comment: I'm using xsl:stylesheet version="1.0". I think it doesn't support 'xsl:for-each-group' as a child.
can you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have access to `group-by` you can consider using the `following-sibling::` axis.

In other words you're looking for something like this:

```
<component>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="Document/service[@class != following-sibling::service/@class]" mode="component" />
</component>

<xsl:template match="service" mode="component">
     <service class="{@class}">
         <!-- etc. -->
     </service>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply.
'following-sibling' is not working. Its giving error 'There are multiple root elements'.
Every service node in my xml has same class value.

Comment: I'd need to see your xslt to be able to comment on this. Perhaps you can post a GitHub gist link or similar?